# Opening Excel from Julia via DotNET

Tags: c#, .net, excel, windows, julia

I want to open Excel from Julia, using DotNET.

My code so far is:

```
using DotNET
Activator = T"System.Activator, System.Runtime"
SystemType = T"System.Type, netstandard"   
appType = SystemType.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application",true)   
excelApp = Activator.CreateInstance(appType)`
```

I face two problem:

1. the Excel vanishes: It occurs shortly in the task manager and vanishes then.
   If I do this code for MS Word ("Word.Application"), then the MS Word instance stays in the task manager.
2. I want to make the Excel visible.

Reading the visible status works like:

BindingFlags = T"System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Runtime"
appType.InvokeMember("Visible", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, wordApp, null)

Making the Excel visible I tried with:

```
parameter = Bool[]
push!(parameter,true)
appType.InvokeMember("Visible", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, excelApp, parameter)`
```

But then came the error message:
CLRException: System.MissingMethodException: Method 'System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember' not found.
This error message I find a bit general, and not that helping.
But probably the parameter is wrong.

I'm not sure, if solving this helps, that the Excel stays alive, and gets visible.

Here is the similar code in C# that works:

The similar code in C# works:

```
Type appType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");
dynamic excelApp = Activator.CreateInstance(appType);
object[] parameter = new object[1];
parameter[0] = true;
appType.InvokeMember("Visible", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, excelApp, parameter);
```

Do you have any suggestions, how to implement this code in Julia?

Answer (score 0):

One has to use the convert-function as written in the DotNET documention. So one solution is:

```
using DotNET

function open_excel_and_workbook(fn::AbstractString)
  Activator = T"System.Activator, System.Runtime"
  SystemType = T"System.Type, netstandard"
  BindingFlags = T"System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Runtime"
  appType = SystemType.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application",true)
  excelApp = Activator.CreateInstance(appType)
  true_parameter = [convert(CLRObject,true)]
  appType.InvokeMember("Visible", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, excelApp, true_parameter)
  workbooks = appType.InvokeMember("Workbooks", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, excelApp, null)
  fn_parameter = [convert(CLRObject, fn)]
  workbook = appType.InvokeMember("Open", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, workbooks, fn_parameter)
end
```